# How do I configure a constraint programmatically in Xcode?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I have a `UIButton` that is placed on a `UIViewController` called Home. Precisely, I'm not sure what should I type in `toItem:`. I browsed through the [Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/secondAttribute) here but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

```
var bottomSpaceUpgradeButtonNSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
item: buttonUpgrade, 
attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 
relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
toItem: buttonUpgrade(Home).Bottom, 
attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 
multiplier: 1, 
constant: -460);
```

This is the constraint I am trying to replicate:

[image: img1]

Comment: I will suggest you to use `Masonry` lib

Comment: Although I can mix up Swift and Objective-C, wouldn't it be a little complicated?

Comment: What about `Snap` https://github.com/Masonry/Snap?

Comment: That looks really nice. However, I need to modify constraints this time only so it isn't for me. If I won't be able to solve my issue I'll use it. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do since you didn't tell us how you want `Home` to be positioned, but I would try this:

```
var bottomSpaceUpgradeButtonNSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: buttonUpgrade, 
   attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 
   relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
      toItem: self.view, 
   attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 
  multiplier: 1, 
    constant: -460);
```

Comment: Home is a `UIViewController`. I would like the button to be positioned at the very bottom of it, so it isn't visible. Thanks for your answer, I will check it out very soon.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. I am getting this error using your code: http://i.imgur.com/tjWNOLP.png. Could you please check out this image? Thanks!

Comment: The error you're seeing indicates that the instance of the `UIViewController` isn't called `Home`.

Comment: Thank you. Shall I declare that `UIViewController` somewhere in the code? I haven't actually declared it. I double checked and my Storyboard `UIViewController` is called Home. Thanks!